# Can I write to hard disk at 1 Gbps?

Tags: c++

I am a bit surprised with the disk speeds that I am getting ..I seem to be able to write a 1GB  file under 1 sec..

```
size_t s = 1*1024*1024;
char* c = new char[s];
FILE* fx = fopen("D:\\test.mine", "wb");
//ensure(fx);
for(int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
{
    fwrite(c,1,s,fx);
}
fclose(fx);
delete[] c;
```

I am a bit hardpressed to understand what could have caused this?
I thought fclose ensured that the data is actually written on the hard disk...?

Comment: Try filling `*c` with data (pseudo-code: `for i = 0 to s: c[i] = rand();`). You may be running into some sort of virtual memory optimization?

Comment: two questions, is the return value of fopen non-null, and is the return value of fwrite equal to s?  aside from that, I agree with the answers given about fclose and buffering.  but it is still worth filling your buffer with some random data and checking the file size after closing.

Comment: @mhk 1Gbps != 1gb/sec. So if you would have a write speed of 1Gbps, then a 1GB file would take 8 seconds to be written to disk (not 1 sec).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard library functions for writing on files just manage their own internal buffers. When writing on files in a modern operating system, even after the `fclose` the data actually just goes in the buffers of the operating system, which will delay the write until it thinks it's a good moment.

The usual way to ensure the data is written to disk is to issue an operating-system specific call to force a write to disk; on POSIX it's `fsync`/`sync`, on Windows you want `FlushFileBuffers`.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. It seems it could also be the hard disk controller itself (i.e transparent to OS) http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/op/cacheWrite-c.html  "If the underlying hard disk has write caching enabled, then the data may not really be on permanent storage when fsync() / fdatasync() return."

Comment: Sure, although normally consumer-grade hard disk controllers have at most about 64 MBs of memory, so this can't account for such a speedup writing a 1 GB file. Also, you can also issue an API call (IIRC a variant of `sync`/`FlushFileBuffers`) to say to the HD to empty all its cache before returning (although some "bad" drives will say they fulfilled the request even if they didn't).

Answer (score 7):

The fclose only flushes the C-library buffers, the system buffers are NOT flushed. Therefor you need a system call, like (f)sync.

Answer (score 0):

fclose() also clears the buffer cache of the stream, so the moment you call fclose() the contents of the unread buffer is wiped away.

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: it clarifies the ambiguity i.e {what could have caused this?} and {i thought fclose ensures disk write}.